# Angular2 check if name exists in the url

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm still learning angular and typescript so excuse me for the stupid question...

I have a list with actors, once clicked on an actor it redirects you to a detail page. The url for the list looks like this

```
localhost:4200/actors
```

so once clicked on an actor it's like this

```
localhost:4200/actors/Jonas
```

However i'm trying to check if the chosen actor actually exists. So if the user manually types a random name in the url it redirects back to the /actors page instead of displaying a blank page.

My component looks like this:

```
actor: Actor;
constructor(
    private actorService: ActorService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(() => {
        if (/* code to check if actor.name exists in the url */ ) {
            this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
                this.actorService.getActor(params.get('name')!))
                .subscribe(actor => this.actor = actor);
        }else {
            this.location.go('/actors');
        }
    });
}
```

anyone an idea how i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not nest the subscribe call. You can use mergeMap or switchMap for this purpose if you want to do a nested asynchronize operation.

However, you can get the name parameter from route path this way:

```
constructor(private router: Router,
           private actorService: ActorService,
           private route: ActivatedRoute,
           private location: Location)
{}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
    .mergeMap(
       (params: Params) => {
          if(params['name']) {
             return this.actorService.getActor(param['name']);
          } 
          return Observable.of(false);
       }
    )
      .subscribe((actor: any) => {
        if (actor ) {
             this.actor = actor;
        }else {
            this.router.navigate(['/actors']);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked, didn't know i couldn't nest the subscribe call

Answer (score 2):

Angular provides a way of resolving data before routing to a specific path called `Resolver`, which is a service that implements the `Resolve` interface from `@angular/router`.

For your example you could build a resolver like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ActorResolver implements Resolve<Actor> {
  constructor(private actorService: ActorService, private router: Router) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Actor> {
    let name = route.paramMap.get('name');
    return this.actorService.getActor(name).take(1).map(actor => {
      if(actor) { // check if actor exists else redirect
        return actor;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/actors']);
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

To provide a resolver you have to add it to the `providers` list of the module. And tell the route to use an resolver like this:

```
{ 
  path: ':name',
  component: ActorDetailsComponent,
  resolve: {
    actor: ActorResolver
  }}
}
```

You can even get your resolved `actor`-data inside your component:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  this.actor = this.route.data.actor;
}
```

You can find more about route resolvers in the [**docs**](https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating).

Comment: Thank you, i'll look in to it and accept your answer if i'll end up using it! Looks promising though

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 this.route.params.subscribe( param => {
            //check if there is a value in name parameter
        if (param['name') {
            // call the data
              this.actorService.getActor(param['name'])
              .then( actor =>{
                    //if the data doesn't exist go to /actors
                   if(!actor)
                     this.location.go('/actors');
               })
        }else {
            this.location.go('/actors');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Actor>'.

that's the error i'm getting after using your solution

Comment: Updated. Just change the subscribe to then

Answer (score 0):

//here is the code

```
this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
        if (params['name']) {
           //do your code
        }else {
            this.location.go('/actors');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
actor: Actor;
constructor(
    private actorService: ActorService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
        if (params['name']) {
            this.actorService.getActor(params.get('name')!))
                .subscribe(actor => this.actor = actor);
        }else {
            this.location.go('/actors');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this gives me the following error:
Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Actor>'.